# Sort value in a column based on condition of another column in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
Company     Company Code     Product Code        Rating
Monster     MNTR             MNTR/Headphone1     3.2
Monster     MNTR             MNTR/Headphone2     3.9
Monster     MNTR             MNTR/Headphone3     NaN
Monster     MNTR             MNTR/Earbuds1       3.5
Bose        BOSE             BOSE/Headphone1     4.0
Bose        BOSE             BOSE/Earbuds1       NaN
Bose        BOSE             BOSE/Earbuds2       2.8
Apple       APLE             APLE/Headphone1     4.5
Sony        SONY             SONY/Headphone1     3.5
Sony        SONY             SONY/Headphone2     4.8
Sony        SONY             SONY/Earbuds1       3.0
Beats       BEAT             BEAT/Headphone1     3.5
Beats       BEAT             BEAT/Headphone2     3.7
```

If the `Rating` is >= 4.0, I want to group by the `Company Code` and bring all the products of the same company to the top, then sort by their `Rating` but keeping the original order of the `Product Code` and the company together. Like Sony, Apple and Bose.

If no ratings of any company products is above 4.0, I would group by the `Company Code` and sort the `Company Code` in alphabetical order. Like Beats and Monster.

```
Company     Company Code     Product Code        Rating
Sony        SONY             SONY/Headphone1     3.5
Sony        SONY             SONY/Headphone2     4.8
Sony        SONY             SONY/Earbuds1       3.0
Apple       APLE             APLE/Headphone1     4.5
Bose        BOSE             BOSE/Headphone1     4.0
Bose        BOSE             BOSE/Earbuds1       NaN
Bose        BOSE             BOSE/Earbuds2       2.8
Beats       BEAT             BEAT/Headphone1     3.5
Beats       BEAT             BEAT/Headphone2     3.7
Monster     MNTR             MNTR/Headphone1     3.2
Monster     MNTR             MNTR/Headphone2     3.9
Monster     MNTR             MNTR/Headphone3     NaN
Monster     MNTR             MNTR/Earbuds1       3.5
```

I thought about dividing the dataframe into two parts - upper and lower, then use concat to join them back. For example,

```
condition = df['Rating'] >= 4.0
df_upper = df.loc[condition]
df_lower = df.loc[~condition]
.
.
.
df_merge = pd.concat([df_upper, df_lower], ignore_index=True)
```

But I have no idea where to apply groupby and sort. Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sorting is used ordered categoricals by [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) with filter `Company Code` of filtered rows and last sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
condition = df['Rating'] >= 4.0

cats1 = df.loc[condition].sort_values('Rating', ascending=False)['Company Code'].unique()
cats2 = df.loc[~condition, 'Company Code'].sort_values().unique()

cats = pd.Index(cats1).union(pd.Index(cats2), sort=False)
print (cats)
Index(['SONY', 'APLE', 'BOSE', 'BEAT', 'MNTR'], dtype='object')

df['Company Code'] = pd.Categorical(df['Company Code'], ordered=True, categories=cats)

df = df.sort_values('Company Code')
print (df)
    Company Company Code     Product Code  Rating
8      Sony         SONY  SONY/Headphone1     3.5
9      Sony         SONY  SONY/Headphone2     4.8
10     Sony         SONY    SONY/Earbuds1     3.0
7     Apple         APLE  APLE/Headphone1     4.5
4      Bose         BOSE  BOSE/Headphone1     4.0
5      Bose         BOSE    BOSE/Earbuds1     NaN
6      Bose         BOSE    BOSE/Earbuds2     2.8
11    Beats         BEAT  BEAT/Headphone1     3.5
12    Beats         BEAT  BEAT/Headphone2     3.7
0   Monster         MNTR  MNTR/Headphone1     3.2
1   Monster         MNTR  MNTR/Headphone2     3.9
2   Monster         MNTR  MNTR/Headphone3     NaN
3   Monster         MNTR    MNTR/Earbuds1     3.5
```